# SBJson parser supposed to give dictionary object but giving NSArray object

Tags: ios

```
 NSDictionary *rData = (NSDictionary *) [jParser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];
```

rData is supposed to be an `NSDictionary` object. But its seems like an array of dictionaries.
Then I am using
`[[rData allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]` to access the first key of the Dictionary. But its crashing saying  `[NSArrayM allKeys]` unrecognised selector.

Comment: What is your question ? And, please share the JSON string you are trying to parse.

Comment: It's not uncommon for JSON to return an array of dictionaries. As others have pointed out, it just depends upon your JSON, which you'd have to share with us. But simply casting the `jParser` results as a `NSDictionary*` doesn't make it a dictionary. It's a function of the JSON data itself.

Comment: An array doesn't have an allKeys method, that's why you're getting that error message. To access the first dictionary, just use rData[0].

Answer (score 0):

JSON data can be an array or a dictionary at the top level. If your JSON starts with a { then it will be a dictionary. If it starts with a [ then it will be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% about what class that you're receive?

About `objectWithString`:

> This method converts its input to an NSData object containing UTF8 and
>   calls -objectWithData: with it.
>
> Returns: The **NSArray** or **NSDictionary** represented by the object, or nil
>   if an error occured.

Try to debug this. You have two (at least!) option:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[rData class]);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[jParser objectWithString:responseString error:nil] class]);
```

Or simply in output:

```
po [[jParser objectWithString:responseString error:nil] class];
```